# Flask python app failing to get app object after initializing

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

`app_instance.py`

```
from app import FlaskApp

app = None


def init_instance(env):
    global app
    app = FlaskApp(env)


def get_instance():
    assert app is not None
    return app
```

`FlaskApp` class is pretty much like this

```
class FlaskApp(object):

    def __init__(self, env):
        self.oauth_manager = .... bla bla ..
        self.clients_manager = .. bla bla ..

        app = Flask(__name__)    
        app.config.from_object(env)    
        app = app_wrapper.wrap(app, app.config['NUM_PROXY_SERVERS'])    
        self.app = app

        self.api = Api(self.app, prefix='/v3', default_mediatype='application/json')
        self.define_routes()
        # Initialize the DB
        self.db = Database(self.app)

        fmt = "%(asctime)s - %(request_id)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=self.app.config.get('LOG_LEVEL'))    
        request_id.init(app, prefix='MY_API_', internal=False)

    def run_server(self):
        self.app.run(host=self.app.config['HOST'], port=self.app.config['PORT'], debug=self.app.config['DEBUG'])

    def define_routes(self):
        # Configure Api Resources
        self.api.add_resource(VersionListController, '/my/route', endpoint='versions')
        more routes here

        self.api.init_app(self.app)
```

in my app controller

```
def is_valid_oauth_token(request):
    from mobile_module import app_instance

    app = app_instance.get_instance()
    # more code here
```

I'm running the app on localhost and getting

```
    assert app is not None
AssertionError
```

How can "fix" this code? should I be importing `from mobile_module import app_instance` in every route access? suggestions please

I should state that this app works in production well behind a Nginx

I guess my question is more about python (how to make this work) and less in flask.

Comment: did you try to use [app context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/)? `from flask import current_app`...

Comment: can you give us the code of FlaskApp class??

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi added to the question

Comment: ok, ! but what do you think about using app factory design pattern ass suggest in my answer?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar app_context did the trick. please write your answer as an answer and i'll approve

Comment: @WebQube thanks. I was glad to help. good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to `get_instance` or `init_instance`(`create_app` etc.).

Flask has [different states](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#the-application-context). App will work in out of request context when you initialize `app` instance(`FlaskApp(env)`).

As I see in your example, you try to get a application in context of request(`def is_valid_oauth_token(request)`). It means that is not initialization of application. This is processing while a request is active. This is other state of application - app was created and work in context of some request. In this case you can get application instance using `from flask import current_app`.

To better understanding how it works/use I recommend to read about `flask._app_ctx_stack`, `app_context()` and `flask.g`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to devellop a flask app simple is to follow the official documentation about simple flask project structure [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/)

you need to organize your floder like this :

```
/yourapplication
    /yourapplication
        __init__.py
        /static
            style.css
        /templates
            layout.html
            index.html
            login.html
            ...
```

and then create your application in init.py file like as follow:

```
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
    """this method will initialise the flask Ap instance """

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hello, World!'
    return app
```

in your yourapplication directory add the run.py to run the app with the following code :

```
from yourapplication import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and if you want to use your controller  you can do this:

```
from yourapplication import create_app
def is_valid_oauth_token(request):
    app = create_app()
    # more code here
```

this is called application factory [design-pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/).

And in addition if you want to put it in production you will need to use WSGI configuration find more [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/)

Comment: That is not the suggested way from the tutorial you linked. Use `import app from foo` in your `views.py` instead and import `views` in `__init__.py` to allow for automagic detection of routes.

Comment: thanks , I add the correct link now , i was talking about [app factory(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) design pattern